# enable product options to be selectable when out of stock in shopify theme

Tags: html, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

my theme's product options are not selectable when out of stock, and therefore a app i am using cannot select them either.

[shopify screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40mev.png)

this is the source code if someone can help me with a fix.

```
{% assign SizeChart_dt = product.metafields.custom.tabladetalla %}
{%- if external == blank and group_product == blank -%}
  <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="{{ cart.currency.iso_code }}">
  <link
    itemprop="availability"
    href="http://schema.org/{% if product.available %}InStock{% else %}OutOfStock{% endif %}"
  >
  {% capture "form_classes" %}
        js-addtocart-form product-single__form{% if product.has_only_default_variant %} product-single__form--no-variants{% endif %}
    {%- endcapture %}
  {% form 'product', product, class: form_classes, data-product-form: '' %}
    {% unless product.has_only_default_variant %}
      {%- for option in product.options_with_values -%}
        {%- assign type = 'label' -%}
        {%- if filter_name_1 != blank and filter_name_1 == option.name -%}
          {%- assign type = select_filter_1 -%}
        {% elsif filter_name_2 != blank and filter_name_2 == option.name %}
          {%- assign type = select_filter_2 -%}
        {% elsif filter_name_3 != blank and filter_name_3 == option.name %}
          {%- assign type = select_filter_3 -%}
        {% endif %}
        <div class="variants-wrapper product-form__item wpb-variants-swatch">
          {% assign current = product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
          {%- if forloop.index == 1 -%}
            {% assign current_option = current.option1 %}
          {% elsif forloop.index == 2 %}
            {% assign current_option = current.option2 %}
          {% else %}
            {% assign current_option = current.option3 %}
          {% endif %}
          <label class="variants__label">
            {{- option.name | escape }}: <span>{{ current_option }}</span></label
          >
          <div class="js-product-select-option--{{ forloop.index }} variants__options">
            {%- if block.settings.product_selector == 'radio' -%}
              {%- assign option_index = forloop.index -%}
              {%- for value in option.values -%}
                {%- assign option_disabled = true -%}
                {%- assign variant_alt = 'false' -%}
                {%- for variant in product.variants -%}
                  {%- if variant.available -%}
                    {%- if option_index == 1 and variant.option1 == value -%}
                      {%- assign option_disabled = false -%}
                      {%- break -%}
                    {%- elsif option_index == 2
                      and variant.option2 == value
                      and variant.option1 == current_variant.option1
                    -%}
                      {%- assign option_disabled = false -%}
                      {%- break -%}
                    {%- elsif option_index == 3
                      and variant.option3 == value
                      and variant.option2 == current_variant.option2
                      and variant.option1 == current_variant.option1
                    -%}
                      {%- assign option_disabled = false -%}
                      {%- break -%}
                    {%- endif -%}
                  {%- endif -%}
                {%- endfor -%}
                {%- for media in product.media -%}
                  {%- if media.alt contains 'Color-' -%}
                    {%- assign variant_img_arr = media.alt | split: '-' -%}
                    {%- if variant_img_arr[1] == value -%}
                      {%- assign variant_alt = 'true' -%}
                      {%- break -%}
                    {%- endif -%}
                  {%- endif -%}
                {%- endfor -%}
                <div class="single-option-selector" data-single-option-button>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    {% if option.selected_value == value %}
                      checked="checked"
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if option_disabled %}
                      disabled="disabled"
                    {% endif %}
                    value="{{ value | escape }}"
                    data-index="option{{ option_index }}"
                    name="option{{ option.position }}"
                    class="js-single-option-selector{% if option_disabled %} disabled{% endif %}"
                    id="ProductSelect-option-{{ option.name | handleize }}-{{ value | escape }}"
                  >
                  {%- if variant_alt == 'true' and type == 'color' -%}
                    {%- for media in product.media -%}
                      {%- if media.alt contains 'Color-' -%}
                        {%- assign media_alt = media.alt | split: '-' -%}
                        {%- if media_alt[1] == value -%}
                          {%- assign variant_img = media.preview_image | img_url: '100x' -%}
                          <label
                            for="ProductSelect-option-{{ option.name | handleize }}-{{ value | escape }}"
                            data-{{ type }}="{{ value }}"
                            title="{{ value | strip | escape }}"
                            style="background:url('{{ variant_img }}');background-size: cover;background-position: center;"
                            class="{% if option_disabled %}disabled{% endif %}"
                          >
                            {{ value | escape }}
                            {%- if type != 'label' -%}
                              <span class="tool-tip">{{ value | escape }}</span>
                            {%- endif -%}
                          </label>
                        {%- endif -%}
                      {%- endif -%}
                    {%- endfor -%}
                  {%- else -%}
                    <label
                      for="ProductSelect-option-{{ option.name | handleize }}-{{ value | escape }}"
                      data-{{ type }}="{{ value }}"
                      title="{{ value | strip | escape }}"
                      class="{{ value | escape }} {% if option_disabled %}disabled{% endif %}"
                    >
                      {{ value | escape }}
                      {%- if type != 'label' -%}
                        <span class="tool-tip">{{ value | escape }}</span>
                      {%- endif -%}
                    </label>
                  {%- endif -%}
                </div>
              {%- endfor -%}
            {%- elsif block.settings.product_selector == 'checkbox' -%}
              {%- assign option_index = forloop.index -%}
              {%- for value in option.values -%}
                {%- assign option_disabled = true -%}
                {%- for variant in product.variants -%}
                  {%- if variant.available -%}
                    {%- if option_index == 1 and variant.option1 == value -%}
                      {%- assign option_disabled = false -%}
                      {%- break -%}
                    {%- elsif option_index == 2
                      and variant.option2 == value
                      and variant.option1 == current_variant.option1
                    -%}
                      {%- assign option_disabled = false -%}
                      {%- break -%}
                    {%- elsif option_index == 3
                      and variant.option3 == value
                      and variant.option2 == current_variant.option2
                      and variant.option1 == current_variant.option1
                    -%}
                      {%- assign option_disabled = false -%}
                      {%- break -%}
                    {%- endif -%}
                  {%- endif -%}
                {%- endfor -%}
                <div class="single-option-selector checkbox" data-single-option-button>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    {% if option.selected_value == value %}
                      checked="checked"
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if option_disabled %}
                      disabled="disabled"
                    {% endif %}
                    value="{{ value | escape }}"
                    data-index="option{{ option_index }}"
                    name="option{{ option.position }}"
                    class="js-single-option-selector{% if option_disabled %} disabled{% endif %}"
                    id="ProductSelect-option-{{ option.name | handleize }}-{{ value | escape }}"
                  >
                  <label
                    for="ProductSelect-option-{{ option.name | handleize }}-{{ value | escape }}"
                    title="{{ value | strip | escape }}"
                    {% if option_disabled %}
                      class="disabled"
                    {% endif %}
                  >
                    {{ value | escape }}
                  </label>
                </div>
              {%- endfor -%}
            {%- else -%}
              <select
                class="js-single-option-selector single-option-selector-{{ section.id }} product-form__input"
                data-id="SingleOptionSelector-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
                data-index="option{{ forloop.index }}"
                data-single-option-select
              >
                {% for value in option.values %}
                  <option
                    value="{{ value | escape }}"
                    {% if option.selected_value == value %}
                      selected="selected"
                    {% endif %}
                  >
                    {{ value | escape }}
                  </option>
                {% endfor %}
              </select>
            {%- endif -%}
          </div>
        </div>
      {%- endfor -%}
    {% endunless %}
    <select name="id" class="js-product-select--{{ section.id }} product-single__variants d-none">
      {%- for variant in product.variants -%}
        {%- if variant.available -%}
          <option
            {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
              selected="selected"
            {% endif %}
            data-sku="{{ variant.sku }}"
            value="{{ variant.id }}"
          >
            {{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}
          </option>
        {%- else -%}
          <option disabled="disabled">{{ variant.title }} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}</option>
        {%- endif -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
    </select>
    {% unless product.has_only_default_variant %}
      {%- if settings.show_size_chart -%}
        <div class="size-guide">
          <div class="title-size-guide">
            <i class="bwp-icon-ruler"></i>
            <h2>{{ 'products.product.size_guide' | t }}</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="img-size-guide">
            <div class="img-size-content">
              <div class="title-size-guide"></div>
              {%- if size_chart -%}
                {% include 'SuperiorHombre' %}
                <img
                  class="size_image"
                  src="{{ size_chart | image_url:width:size_chart.width,height:size_chart.height }}"
                  alt="{{ size_chart.alt | escape }}"
                  width="{{ size_chart.width }}"
                  height="{{ size_chart.height }}"
                >
              {%- else -%}
                {%- if settings.type_sizechart == 'image' -%}
                  <img
                    class="size_image"
                    src="{{ settings.img_size_chart | image_url:width:settings.img_size_chart.width,height:settings.img_size_chart.height }}"
                    alt="{{ settings.img_size_chart.alt | escape }}"
                    width="{{ settings.img_size_chart.width }}"
                    height="{{ settings.img_size_chart.height }}"
                  >
                {%- else -%}
                  {% if SizeChart_dt == 'SuperiorHombre' %}
                    {% include 'SuperiorHombre' %}

                  {% elsif SizeChart_dt == 'InferiorMujer' %}
                    {% include 'InferiorMujer' %}

                  {% elsif SizeChart_dt == 'InferiorHombre' %}
                    {% include 'InferiorHombre' %}

                  {% elsif SizeChart_dt == 'SuperiorMujer' %}
                    {% include 'SuperiorMujer' %}
                  {% endif %}
                {%- endif -%}
              {%- endif -%}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {%- endif -%}
    {% endunless %}
    {%- if block.settings.product_available_enable -%}
      <div class="content-variant_inventory">
        {% if current_variant.inventory_management == 'shopify' %}
          {% if current_variant.inventory_quantity > 0 %}
            {%- assign stock = current_variant.inventory_quantity -%}
            {%- assign sold = block.settings.total_product_solid -%}
            {%- assign total = stock | plus: sold -%}
            {%- assign percent = stock | times: 100.00 | divided_by: total | round: 4 -%}
            <div class="js-product-avaiable product-avaiable">
              <div id="variant-inventory_percent" class="show" style="--progress-bar-width:{{ percent }}%">
                {{ 'products.product.left_in_stock_html' | t: current_variant: current_variant.inventory_quantity }}
                <div class="content-percent"><div class="percent"></div></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {%- endif -%}
    <div class="product-single__buttons">
      {% comment %}Product quantity{% endcomment %}
      {%- if block.settings.quantity_enabled and current_variant.available -%}
        <div class="js-quantity-selector product-quantity">
          <label for="Quantity" class="product-quantity__label">{{ 'products.product.quantity' | t }}</label>
          <div class="product-quantity__selector">
            {%- if block.settings.quantity_selector == 'text' -%}
              <div class="wpbingo-qty">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="js-qty-adjust wpbingo-qty__adjust wpbingo-qty__adjust--minus"
                  aria-label="{{ 'cart.general.reduce_quantity' | t }}"
                >
                  <i class="feather-minus"></i>
                </button>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="quantity"
                  class="js-qty-number wpbingo-qty__number"
                  value="1"
                  min="1"
                  aria-label="quantity"
                  pattern="[0-9]*"
                >
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="js-qty-adjust wpbingo-qty__adjust wpbingo-qty__adjust--plus"
                  aria-label="{{ 'cart.general.increase_quantity' | t }}"
                >
                  <i class="feather-plus"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            {%- else -%}
              <select name="quantity" id="Quantity" class="product-quantity__select">
                {%- for i in (1..10) -%}
                  <option
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                      selected="selected"
                    {% endif %}
                    value="{{ i }}"
                  >
                    {{ i }}
                  </option>
                {%- endfor -%}
              </select>
            {%- endif -%}
          </div>
        </div>
      {%- endif -%}
      {% comment %}Add to cart button{% endcomment %}
      <div class="product-single__add-to-cart">
        <button
          class="btn btn--add-to-cart{% if block.settings.enable_payment_button %} btn--secondary-accent{% endif %}"
          {% unless current_variant.available %}
            disabled="disabled"
          {% endunless %}
          type="submit"
          name="add"
        >
          <span class="btn__text">
            {% if current_variant.available %}
              {% if current_variant.incoming and current_variant.inventory_quantity == 0 %}
                {{ 'products.product.pre_order' | t }}
              {% else %}
                {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}
              {% endif %}
            {% else %}
              {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
            {% endif %}
          </span>
        </button>
        {%- if product.handle != blank and section.settings.product_button_wishlist -%}
          <div class="button-wishlist">
            <button
              type="button"
              aria-label="Add to wishlist"
              class=""
              button-wishlist
              data-product-handle="{{ product.handle }}"
            ></button>
          </div>
        {%- endif -%}
      </div>
      {% if block.settings.enable_payment_button and current_variant.available %}
        {% comment %} terms and conditions checkbox {% endcomment %}
        {% if settings.show_terms_conditions %}
          <p class="ajaxcart_terms_conditions">
            <input style="float:none; vertical-align: middle;" type="checkbox" class="agree_terms_conditions">
            <label style="display:inline; float:none" for="agree">
              {{ settings.content_terms_conditions }}
            </label>
          </p>
        {% endif %}
        {% comment %} end terms and conditions checkbox {% endcomment %}
        {{ form | payment_button }}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  {% endform %}
  {% unless current_variant.available %}
    {% include 'back-in-stock-form' %}
  {% endunless %}
{%- elsif external != blank and group_product == blank -%}
  <div class="product-single__buttons product-single__add-to-cart">
    <a class="product-single__external" href="{{ external }}">{{ 'products.product.buy_product' | t }}</a>
    {%- if product.handle != blank and section.settings.product_button_wishlist -%}
      <div class="button-wishlist">
        <button type="button" aria-label="Add to wishlist" class="" data-product-handle="{{ product.handle }}"></button>
      </div>
    {%- endif -%}
  </div>
{%- elsif group_product != blank -%}
  <form method="post" id="group_table_product" action="/cart/add" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="product">
    <div class="group_table">
      {% for group_ids in group_product_array %}
        {% assign product_id = group_ids | plus: 0 %}
        {% paginate collections.all.products by 1000 %}
          {% for product in collections.all.products %}
            {%- if product.id == product_id -%}
              <div data-product_id="{{ product_id }}" class="item-product-group">
                <div class="product-content">
                  <div class="product-thumb">
                    <a href="{{ product.url }}">
                      {% include 'img-global' with image: product.featured_image, class: "featured-banner__img", effect: "fade-in" %}
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="product-info">
                    <h3 class="product-title">
                      <a href="{{ product.url }}">{{ product.title }}</a>
                    </h3>
                    {% assign number_variant = 0 %}
                    {%- for variant in product.variants -%}
                      {% assign number_variant = number_variant | plus: 1 %}
                    {%- endfor -%}
                    {%- if number_variant == 1 -%}
                      {%- for variant in product.variants -%}
                        {% if variant.inventory_management == 'shopify' and variant.inventory_policy != 'continue' %}
                          {% if variant.inventory_quantity == 0 %}
                            {% assign out_stock = true %}
                          {%- endif -%}
                        {%- endif -%}
                        <div class="product-price">{{ product.price | money }}</div>
                        <input
                          name="items[][id]"
                          type="hidden"
                          value="{{ variant.id  }}"
                          {% if out_stock %}
                            disabled="disabled"
                          {%- endif -%}
                        >
                        {% if out_stock %}
                          <div class="stock">{{ 'products.product.out_stock' | t }}</div>
                        {%- endif -%}
                      {%- endfor -%}
                    {%- else -%}
                      <select name="items[][id]" class="js-product-btp--{{ section.id }} product-single__variants">
                        {%- for variant in product.variants -%}
                          {%- if variant.available -%}
                            <option
                              {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
                                selected="selected"
                              {% endif %}
                              data-price="{{ variant.price }}"
                              value="{{ variant.id }}"
                            >
                              {{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}
                            </option>
                          {%- else -%}
                            <option disabled="disabled">
                              {{ variant.title }} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
                            </option>
                          {%- endif -%}
                        {%- endfor -%}
                      </select>
                    {%- endif -%}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="quantity-content">
                  {%- if out_stock -%}
                    <div class="wpbingo-qty">
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        class="js-qty-adjust wpbingo-qty__adjust wpbingo-qty__adjust--minus"
                        aria-label="{{ 'cart.general.reduce_quantity' | t }}"
                        disabled="disabled"
                      >
                        <i class="feather-minus"></i>
                      </button>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        name="items[][quantity]"
                        class="js-qty-number wpbingo-qty__number"
                        value="0"
                        min="0"
                        aria-label="quantity"
                        pattern="[0-9]*"
                        disabled="disabled"
                      >
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        class="js-qty-adjust wpbingo-qty__adjust wpbingo-qty__adjust--plus"
                        aria-label="{{ 'cart.general.increase_quantity' | t }}"
                        disabled="disabled"
                      >
                        <i class="feather-plus"></i>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  {%- else -%}
                    <div class="wpbingo-qty">
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        class="js-qty-adjust wpbingo-qty__adjust wpbingo-qty__adjust--minus"
                        aria-label="{{ 'cart.general.reduce_quantity' | t }}"
                      >
                        <i class="feather-minus"></i>
                      </button>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        name="items[][quantity]"
                        class="js-qty-number wpbingo-qty__number"
                        value="1"
                        min="0"
                        aria-label="quantity"
                        pattern="[0-9]*"
                      >
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        class="js-qty-adjust wpbingo-qty__adjust wpbingo-qty__adjust--plus"
                        aria-label="{{ 'cart.general.increase_quantity' | t }}"
                      >
                        <i class="feather-plus"></i>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  {%- endif -%}
                </div>
              </div>
            {%- endif -%}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endpaginate %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% comment %}Add to cart button{% endcomment %}
    <div class="product-group__add-to-cart product-single__buttons">
      <button type="submit" class="add-group-to-cart">
        {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}
      </button>
      {%- if product.handle != blank -%}
        <div class="button-wishlist">
          <button
            type="button"
            aria-label="Add to wishlist"
            class=""
            button-wishlist
            data-product-handle="{{ product.handle }}"
          ></button>
        </div>
      {%- endif -%}
    </div>
  </form>
{%- endif -%}
```

"I already tried removing the 'class="disabled"' from the loop of the selectors, but it's not working."

Comment: Simply allow the product from the backend after sell after out to stock, if want to select and sell it